Someone got access to my private key and moved the funds, how can I track my account activity?
Is there a way where I can check my account logs?

You can track the transfer of funds using the Block Explorer (like Etherscan, Polygonscan, BscScan, etc.)  depending on the chain/network on which you had funds that are being moved.
